# A simple Query is duplicating records

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, record

I have two(2) Tables. The first one named `TABLE` have N rows with unique _A (KEY), and the second named `TABLE_AUX` have 0 rows, then i'm just running the next Query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_AUX(_A,_B,_C) 
SELECT A,B,C FROM TABLE;
```

After evaluated the query, I have:

```
a) N = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE_AUX

b) K = SELECT SUM(Q.CNT-1) 
       FROM ( SELECT COUNT(1) as CNT, _A 
              FROM TABLE_AUX GROUP BY _A HAVING COUNT(1)>1
       ) Q;

c) M = SELECT COUNT(Q._A) 
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT _A 
             FROM TABLE_AUX) Q

, WHERE N = M + K, then M < N 

d) Zero = 0 = SELECT COUNT(1) 
              FROM TABLE T 
              WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                                 FROM TABLE_AUX TA 
                                 WHERE TA._A = T._A );

e) P = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE T, TABLE_AUX TA WHERE T._A = TA._A;

, WHERE P = N + K, then N < P
```

Is strange, in some cases there are repeated results. But not in all cases. Anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: format the table and queries correctly !

Comment: Yes, I'm overloading operators to highlight the cardinality of each of the results. They are not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Use Distinct keyword in Select query.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_AUX(_A,_B,_C) 
SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Okey, but the size of TABLE is N, if TABLE.A is unique then the result of DISTINCT have to be N. I'm going to probe it, to see if this solves it. Thx!